# QSignalSpy wait and two signals

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, qt5, signals-slots

I'm trying to write an unit test for a class in a Qt-based project (Qt 5, C++03).

```
class Transaction { // This is just a sample class
//..
public signals:
   void succeeded();
   void failed();
}

Transaction* transaction = new Transaction(this);
QSignalSpy spy(transaction, SIGNAL(succeeded()));
transaction->run();
spy.wait(5000); // wait for 5 seconds
```

I want my test to run faster.
How to interrupt this `wait()` call after signal `failed()` is emitted, in case of failed transaction?

I do not see any slots available in the QSignalSpy class.

I should use QEventLoop instead?

Comment: If you call spy.wait() without parameters, it would return true as soon as the signal is emitted within 5000ms. You don't need to wait for 5000ms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution with `QTestEventLoop`:

```
QTestEventLoop loop;
QObject::connect(transaction, SIGNAL(succeeded()), &loop, SLOT(exitLoop()));
QObject::connect(transaction, SIGNAL(failed()), &loop, SLOT(exitLoop()));
transaction->run();
loop.enterLoopMSecs(3000);
```

Solution with a timer and `QEventLoop`:

```
Transaction* transaction = new Transaction(this);
QSignalSpy spy(transaction, SIGNAL(succeeded()));  
QEventLoop loop;  
QTimer timer;
QObject::connect(transaction, SIGNAL(succeeded()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
QObject::connect(transaction, SIGNAL(failed()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
timer.start(3000);
loop.exec();
transaction->run();
QCOMPARE(spy.count(), 1);
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if the code that emits `suceeded()` and `failed()` already depends on Qt's event loop. Do you not use Qt's event loop?

Answer (score 8):

You'll probably have to use a loop and manually call [`QTest::qWait()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#qWait) while neither signal has been emitted:

```
QSignalSpy succeededSpy(transaction, SIGNAL(succeeded()));
QSignalSpy failedSpy(transaction, SIGNAL(failed()));
for (int waitDelay = 5000; waitDelay > 0 && succeededSpy.count() == 0 && failedSpy.count() == 0; waitDelay -= 100) {
    QTest::qWait(100);
}

QCOMPARE(succeededSpy.count(), 1);
```